# GitLab Runner & Docker: ERROR: Preparation failed: Error: No such image

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

When attempting to pull public images (e.g. `python:3.6`, `node:latest`) from Docker, our GitLab runner failed with the following error message:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.2.0 (a987417a)
  on GitLab Runner XYZ
Using Docker executor with image python:3.6 ... 00:17
Starting service python:3.6 ...
Pulling docker image python:3.6 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error: No such image: python:3.6 (executor_docker.go:199:0s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was we exceeded [Dockers pull rate limit](https://www.docker.com/blog/scaling-docker-to-serve-millions-more-developers-network-egress/):

- Free plan – anonymous users: 100 pulls per 6 hours
- Free plan – authenticated users: 200 pulls per 6

### How can I check my current rate?

See https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/#how-can-i-check-my-current-rate

### How to increase the rate limit?

Authenticate with Docker Hub to increase to 200 pulls per 6 hours:

```
docker login
```

Alternatively you can [cache Docker images to reduce the number of calls to DockerHub](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/10/30/mitigating-the-impact-of-docker-hub-pull-requests-limits/) from your CI/CD infrastructure.